# Order list of options based on MySQL query - PHP

Tags: php, html, mysql

I am presenting a list of options to the user based on a database query. The results are being fetched correctly however they are currently unordered and  I would like to display them in alphabetical order in the option list. I have tried several solutions so far with "ORDER BY" on the query level however with no success. Is there a simple way to achieve this? (The list contains 1000+ results) The code is as follows:

```
<?php
$user_id = $_SESSION['user_id'];
$sql = "SELECT * FROM add_bulding WHERE description<>''";
$query = $this->db->query($sql);
$building_title = $query->result_array();
?>


<div>
     <select>
          <option value="">Select Building</option>
          <?php foreach ($building_title as $value) { ?>
              <option value = "<?php echo $value['id']; ?>">
              <?php echo $value['title']; ?> 
              </option>
          <?php
          }
          ?>
     </select>
</div>
```

Comment: ORDER BY title should work

Comment: adding order by to the query should give you the correct ordering.  Please show your order by query, and a small sample of the data and why it is wrong

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try changing your query to:

```
$sql = "SELECT * FROM add_bulding WHERE description<>'' ORDER BY title DESC";
```

Answer (score 0):

Sounds like you want a query like:

```
SELECT id, title FROM add_bulding WHERE description<> ORDER BY title desc
```

Alternately, you can sort it in php:

```
<?php
$tmp = array();
foreach ($building_title as $value){
    $tmp[$value['id']] = $value['title'];
}
ksort($tmp);
foreach ($tmp as $k => $v) {
  print "<option value=\"" + $k + "\">" + $v + "</option>\n";
}
?>
```

However, in either case, be sure to sanitize your values so you don't end up with XSS problems.

Answer (score 0):

Try this query :

```
$sql = "SELECT * FROM add_bulding WHERE description<>'' ORDER BY title";
```

If you want to get title data with alphabetical order then you can write 'ASC' or do not need to write any after ORDER BY title.

But you want to get title data with descending order then you need to write 'DESC' after  ORDER BY title
I hope you will get solution.